# Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager alpine java 17

Tags: java, docker

We're trying to run our java 8 application inside alpine_java-17 container.
Everything compiles and works fine except one thing.

One functionality regarding excel doesn't work. In the logs I found:

```
Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager
```

Previously when we ran our app inside java8 container we didn't have this issue since we had command to install required packages:

```
RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig libfreetype6
```

But now since we have alpine 17 we changed the above command to

```
RUN apk add fontconfig
RUN apk add freetype
```

I tried to install libfreetype6 using RUN apk add libfreetype6 but docker returned me an error:

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  libfreetype6 (no such package):
    required by: world[libfreetype6]
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add libfreetype6' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It seems like freetype is not the same as libfreetype6, but libfreetype6 is missing.

Can someone please help to understand the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here with no solution yet. As far as I can tell `libfreetype6` and `freetype` are roughly the same: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libfreetype6/filelist and https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=freetype&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=x86

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I encountered the problem in a docker image based on `eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine` running a webapp that generates excel files using apache poi. After adding the packages `fontconfig` and `ttf-dejavu` as follows (it seems that `freetype` is a dependency of `fontconfig` and therefore does not have to be installed explicitly):

```
RUN apk add --no-cache fontconfig ttf-dejavu
```

not only the class `FontText.java` given here:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/issues/529#issuecomment-811687786

ran successfully, but also it was possible to generate excel files, which before resulted in the exception given in the question and in this exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/java/openjdk/lib/libfontmanager.so: Error loading shared library libfreetype.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/java/openjdk/lib/libfontmanager.so)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
```

Comment: `ttf-dejavu` should be replaced with `fonts-dejavu` from Ubuntu 20